# Fade Div1 In/Out Then Fade Div2 In?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm trying to fade in the div "frame1" in while "frame2" is hidden, and then when "frame1" fades out I want "frame2" to fade in where "frame1" faded out.  I tried searching, but havent had luck since most that I have come across are onclick events.

```
<div id="frames">
    <div id="frame1">
        <p>first text to appear here</p>
    </div>
    <div id="frame2">
        <p>second text to appear here after first text fades out</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If frame1 is shown and frame2 is hidden, you can fadeout frame1 and then fadein frame2 by using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#frame1").fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $("#frame2").fadeIn('slow');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolute position both divs relative to the wrapper div so they're superposed and then use the callback function from the fadeOut event in the first div.

```
$('#frame1').fadeOut('fast', function(){
    $('#frame2').fadeIn('fast'); // Callback
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, frame 2 is hidden, then hiding frame 1 and showing frame 2 with this fade out fade in..

```
 $("#frame1").fadeOut('slow', function(){
 $("#frame2").fadeIn('slow');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery [.fadeTo()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeto/)

```
$('#frame1').fadeTo('slow', 1, function() {
  $('#frame2').fadeTo(600, 0);
});
```

- duration: examples above as `slow` and `600` (string or number in milliseconds)
- opacity: examples above as `1` and `0` (number ranging from 0-1)

or

using jQuery [.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

```
$("#frame1").fadeOut('fast', function(){
  $("#frame2").fadeIn(100);
});
```

- duration: examples above as `fast` and `100` (string or number in milliseconds)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#frame1').fadeOut('slow');
$('#frame2').delay('slow').fadeIn('slow');
```